# Addin word Manifest

Tags: manifest, office-addins, word-addins

I'm developing a word addin
When I run Word the addin icon appears but if I open it an error occurs

[image]

If I try to reload the component this error occurs on the manifest

System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException: Exception when reading manifest from file:///C:/XXXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/WordWebAddIn1.xml: nvalid manifest or file cannot be opened. ---> System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException: Error parsing and creating manifest DOM. The following parsing errors were detected:
-HRESULT:   0x8007001f
Riga iniziale:     0
Colonna iniziale:  0
File host:      ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException:
A device connected to the system is not working. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007001F)
in System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.IsolationInterop.CreateCMSFromXml(Byte[] buffer, UInt32 bufferSize, IManifestParseErrorCallback Callback, Guid& riid)
in System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.LoadCMSFromStream(Stream stream)

What can I do ?
Thanks in advance